# Get Data from an Object in the Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get an object from my browser / get the data stored in the object from my browser?

1. The user presses submit button after filling out a form with a bad credit card number (a scenario I am testing), which triggers a jQuery function `SubmitAPI()` (code below).
2. Google Chrome console displays `400 Bad Request` error (because the credit card number is bad) as well as an API Response holding the object with the declined credit card data (response below)
3. I specifically need to grab `"response_type":"D","response_code":"U20","response_desc":"INVALID CREDIT CARD NUMBER"` because I want to display this error message to the user. How can I do this in jQuery?
4. I have tried for hours to figure this out. I use `response.response.response_type` to get the Response Type when the transaction is successful (approved credit card). However with a bad credit card number, this same attempt results in "undefined". So, instead, I just want to grab the data from my Google Chrome browser that managed to get the Response Code response.

PART 1: jQuery Code (Directly from the API's documentation - except I changed the credit card to be a bad number)

```
  function SubmitAPI() {
    var settings = {
        "url": 
    "https://sandbox.forte.net/api/v3/organizations/org_ID/locations/loc_ID/transactions",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "X-Forte-Auth-Organization-Id": "org_ID",
            "Authorization": "ID",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "data": JSON.stringify({ "action": "sale", "authorization_amount": 102.45, "subtotal_amount": 99.95, "billing_address": { "first_name": "Jennifer", "last_name": "McFly" }, "card": { "card_type": "visa", "name_on_card": "Jennifer McFly", "account_number": "41111sdf11111111", "expire_month": "12", "expire_year": "2017", "card_verification_value": "123" } }),
    };

    $.ajax(settings).always(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

PART 2: Console Response:

```
400 (Bad Request)
```

PART 3: Response Object in Browser:

```
{"location_id":"loc_241789","action":"sale","authorization_amount":102.45,"entered_by":"59ae172b3bd78bed493ecd5892975764","billing_address":{"first_name":"Jennifer","last_name":"McFly"},"card":{"name_on_card":"Jennifer McFly","last_4_account_number":"1111","masked_account_number":"****1111","expire_month":12,"expire_year":2017,"card_type":"visa"},"response":{"environment":"sandbox","response_type":"D","response_code":"U20","response_desc":"INVALID CREDIT CARD NUMBER"}}
```

Comment: 400 bad request means the request you send to the server was somehow incorrect, or the server couldn't interprete it. I would suggest you try [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and do POST requests through the app. It's a good place for debugging.

Comment: `.done()` is for when the request is successful. If you want to catch the error, use `.fail()`

Comment: so `response.response.response_desc`

Comment: So what is the issue. Does done() get called. What is in `response`? (Is it the 3rd line?) Is it an object or string when it is logged?

Comment: @epascarello I need to display this data to the user: `"response_type":"D","response_code":"U20","response_desc":"INVALID CREDIT CARD NUMBER"` which Google Chrome shows in Inspect > Network > Response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using error handler for the Ajax call and was able to get the error message with no issues.

```js
var settings = {
  "url": "https://sandbox.forte.net/api/v3/organizations/org_381529/locations/loc_241789/transactions",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "X-Forte-Auth-Organization-Id": "org_381529",
    "Authorization": "Basic NTlhZTE3MmIzYmQ3OGJlZDQ5M2VjZDU4OTI5NzU3NjQ6ZWUwZTZiZDA4ZThlMWNhNWQ3MzUyNGU0ZWU5ZDFjNTg=",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "data": JSON.stringify({
    "action": "sale",
    "authorization_amount": 102.45,
    "subtotal_amount": 99.95,
    "billing_address": {
      "first_name": "Jennifer",
      "last_name": "McFly"
    },
    "card": {
      "card_type": "visa",
      "name_on_card": "Jennifer McFly",
      "account_number": "41111sdf11111111",
      "expire_month": "12",
      "expire_year": "2017",
      "card_verification_value": "123"
    }
  }),
};

$.ajax(settings).error(function(xhr) {
  console.log("Error", xhr.responseJSON.response.response_desc);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You beat me by 5 seconds! Please, use `.fail()`, as `.error()` has been deprecated 
 and removed in jQuery 3.0 ([Ctrl+F ".error" in these docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))